# Instantiate a view controller on AppDelegate, understanding

Tags: ios, objective-c, controller, viewcontroller

I am learning iOS developing following some tutorials. In one of them says:
`Create a new view controller, call it StoreViewController, and inside the app delegate instantiate a new object for this controller and put it inside a new navigation controller`

I have created a new ViewController, with .h .m and .xib files, an had put this code on AppDelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
StoreViewController *trStore = [[StoreViewController alloc] init];
```

Now I was seeing at `...and put it inside a new navigation controller` but I cannot understand that. I have an storyboard with a NavigationController, may I have to link this StoreViewController with my Navigation controller?? What do you understand??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I tried to use the tags which I did consider more appropriate for my question. What tags do you think are better? Say it to me please in order to change and do not fail again.

Comment: You can [see what has been edited on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35652371/revisions) and draw conclusions from there. Pay attention to the tag decriptions when adding tags. 'iphone' is intended for hardware-specific questions.

Comment: I understand, I am grateful for the help you gave to me, thats a better way to maintain StackOverflow community. Sorry to all for my bad understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up different methods for instantiating view controllers.

When you are using storyboards, your main view controller does get instantiated from that storyboard. Just Add a new `UIViewController` scene to your storyboard and set the class to `StoreViewController` in the Inspector, like so:

[image]

Then, add that as the rootViewController of the `UINavigationController` like so:

[image]

**Edit**:
Please try to only use tutorials appropriate for the xcode/ios version you are targetting. A lot has changed in the last few years and using old tutorials without an understanding of those changes is not to be recommended, because it leads to problems like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. The problem is that I have no much time for this develop, and I have to do a NewsStand app (newsstand disappeared so much time ago) and the few tutorials that I had found are from Xcode 4, I know its a bit difficult, but it is the only way I have found.

Comment: First of all, glad to help; consider using the upvote and accept buttons to say 'thank you' the SE way. Secondly, you'd be better of understanding the fundamentals first, then expand to more complex scenarios. Try to cherry-pick the things from the old tutorial while using the programming guides from apple and more current tutorials for the basic things.

Comment: I cannot obtain the Relationship segue for rootViewController. If I right click-drag the ViewController to the rootView, the contextual menu shows Manual Segue (Options: Show, Show Detail, Modal, ...) and Non-Adaptative Manual Segue. If simply right click the new View Controller and drag relationship to view controller, Xcode crashes.

Comment: Make sure you remove the root view controller connection that xcode puts between a `UINavigationController` and a `UITableViewController` by default. There should be no connections going to or from the navigation controller when you start right-dragging.

Comment: Same result, no Relationship segue options, and crash if right-drag if go with Relationship.

Comment: Please check your storyboard for problems, your xcode version. And that you drag from the `UINavigationController` scene, not the view. This should work.